# javascript code to not allow the page to load without login

Tags: javascript

I have coded a login page. If the Login credentials are correct I have to redirect the page to another page.

If I copy the URL/path of home page and paste in address bar it shouldn't load. It must be redirected to Login page.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?  What is your question?

Comment: can we see the code you have? also immediately I'm starting to feel Javascript isn't the best for this. Take a look into PHP `header`

Comment: take a look into answers..........

Answer (score 2):

Its best to use the server side language to authenticate the user request, i.e, `Asp.net, PHP, JSP` etc. And if you cannot use server side scripting than use `HTML5` [sessionStorage](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/domstorage.shtml).

```
sessionStorage.setItem("mykey", "Some Value") ;
```

And now get the key value in your `home page` to authenticate, if `null or undefined` then redirect to login page.

```
var value = sessionStorage.mykey;
if(value =='undefined' || value == null || value == undefined)
{
   window.location.href="/login";
}
```

**Note:** DOM Storage (sessionStorage and localStorage) is supported in the following browsers- FF3.5+, Chrome4+, Safari4+, Opera10.5+, and IE8+.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access home without being logged in. The server should be returning a redirect respons. It is not done from the client.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to do this kind of task in java code, rather than javascript. Anyways for the solution:

get user id on jsp page, using scriplet.

```
<script>
var user = '<%= request.getUserPrincipal()%>';
            if (user == 'null')
                window.location.href="/login";
</script>
```

If the value is null then user is not logged in. use window.location.href (javascript) to 
redirect the user in this case.

replace the login page URL with your URL.

Comment: I couldnt get value of the user. I tried with "var user = 'window.document.getElementById("userid").value';" Note: userid is the textbox name in login page

Comment: @user1825788: Does that textbox has a value?, if yes, then how is it populated?

Answer (score 0):

It requires to manage session. In general all these kind of session management done by server side technologies like java, .NET etc.

You can do it by using JavaScript also but it is very less secure and reliable.

If the login is successful create a one browser cookie which just stores a boolean value saying that he is valid user and redirect to home page. In home page check for the login cookie value. If its value is not valid then redirect user again login page by displaying exception message.